# Thinkpad's system update corrupted my BIOS on a W530

Tags: bios, thinkpad, lenovo-laptop

I've used Lenovo's system update to update the BIOS on a W530
I ran the system update tool which recommended this update.

When ran it opened a command prompt several times and then rebooted the laptop but it failed to boot - all I get is 2 sequences of 5 short beeps and then a blank screen.

Is there a way to recover?

Comment: Five short beeps and a blank screen.  System board error https://www.google.com/search?q=lenovo+beep+codes&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Comment: Thanks David, its just that it was all fine until the reboot following the bios update, so I find it hard to believe that the board suddenly failed...

Comment: BIOS (or rather UEFI) is a software part of system board, so yeah, if the BIOS is corrupted then effectively the system board has failed. The beep code is correct, but not very helpful.

Comment: :-) fair enough, question remains - I assume its not a sudden hardware failure, but rather a bad BIOS update, is there a way to get the laptop working again?

Comment: You could try clearing the cmos "Remove the main battery, depress the power button 10 times in succession, each time depressing it for at least two seconds. Reinstall the battery." https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-W-Series-Laptops/No-Post-on-W530/td-p/915343

Comment: Time to call Lenovo?